# Simulate light bulb load with LED

Tags: led, ac

I'm working on a project where I want to be able to conect 230VAC and power one LED.
The load when measured need to be about 15W.

What would be the best and least heat to disipate?

It's to simulate the load one light in a trafficsignal system.

When done it will be 8 sets of 4 LEDs (white, red, amber and green) so in total 32 LEDs and about 480 watts so there will be a good heatsink for it.

Edit: The traffic light controller is measuring to make sure lights are working so when testing in a lab it needs to appear to have a load that is similar to the real thing.

Comment: *What would be the best and least heat to disipate?* - well the LED is going to dissipate 15 watts so that's the "least". The "best" is also 15 watts from the perspective of trying to avoid global warming etc.. Maybe try thinking about a valid question for this site?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  You're asking how to make a 15W dummy load for testing?  Get a resistor or some more LEDs.  Or are you asking about traffic lights?  Could you clarify what information in your question is relevant?

Comment: Sorry, how would a good circuit look like. We have a unit that does this but can't take it apart without breaking it (it's old) and it looks like there is a transistor in it aswell.

Comment: *how would a good circuit look like* It would look very good ;-) You're asking things that assumes we have a crystal ball and are looking over your shoulder. *it looks like there is a transistor in* That remark is pointless without proper details. A TO92 package looks like "a transistor" but there are NPNs, PNPs, MOSFETs, Thyristors and ICs that all use that package.

Comment: The load will only be 480W when all traffic lights are on at once. That sounds ... dangerous.

Comment: Realise the question was poorly written, I appreciate the time taken to help me. And deem it solved with the answer provided by @Bimpelrekkie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You present this as if your design solution needs to be much smaller, use LEDs, but still dissipate 480 W and behave the same as a bunch of 15 W lightbulbs?!?

In order to **properly** test a traffic light controller that is going to control lightbulbs, **you will need lightbulbs for testing**.

Why?

Because a lightbulb, when cold, will have a low resistance and will draw a current peak when switched on. You cannot easily do the same with a LED.

LEDs are fundamentally very different beasts than lightbulbs. LEDs need a low voltage. LEDs cannot work on a constant voltage, they need a (somewhat) constant current.

You can put LEDs in series to increase the voltage and use all kinds of circuits to make them work on 230 V AC. But from the controller's perspective, such an emulated load will look **very different** from a real lightbulb.

You could use **resistors** to emulate the lightbulb. Then the resistors would dissipate most of the power (use power resistors, heatsinks are optional depending on what resistors you choose) and the make a simple circuit (capacitive dropper) to power an **indicator LED**. But realize that the resistors do behave differently from a lightbulb as resistors have a constant resistance, lightbulbs do not.

It all depends on what level you need to do the testing of your controller.

If you only need to be able to test that the lights go on/off properly, add LEDs in your design to monitor the signals that go to the stage that drives the lightbulbs.

If you're using TRIACs / Thyristors to switch the lightbulbs then using a low power LED lamp might not work as the hold current could be too low. Then adding load resistors to make more current flow could suffice (maybe less than 15 W also works).

Comment: Thank you for the answer as have made look at it from a different angle.